# how to select the dates if two dates selected in asp.net calendar control with single calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

this is requirement in my current project and i wanted to select date december 1 and i will select december9 all the dates in between should get selected including selected dates.

in a single calendar i need to allow for all the 12 months.

for each month i need to select for example if i select 3rd november and 10 th november all the dates including selected dates should get selected and after clicking on save button it should take first and last dates of selected dates to store them

can any one help me out in this please i am suffering from two days

thanks in advance

i am using asp.net c#.

```
protected void calendar_onDayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) < 0)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            }


                if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) //&& _lstholiday.Contains(e.Day.Date))
                {
                    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
                List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)ViewState["HolidaysList"];
                if (newList.Contains(e.Day.Date)) //&& _lstholiday.Contains(e.Day.Date))
                {
                    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

                    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["WorkingDays"]) == Convert.ToDecimal(22))
                {
                    if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) 
                    {
                        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

                        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    }
                }
                if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
                {

                    list.Add(e.Day.Date);
                }
                Session["SelectedDates"] = list;
                if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
                {
                    if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
                    {
                        List<DateTime> _newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];

                        foreach (DateTime datecalendar1 in _newList)
                        {

                            //if (_newList.Contains(e.Day.Date))
                            //{
                            //    //calendar.SelectedDates.Remove(e.Day.Date);

                            //}
                            //else
                            //    list.Add(e.Day.Date);
                            if (datecalendar1.Date != calendar.SelectedDate.Date)
                            {
                                if (datecalendar1.Month == calendar.SelectedDate.Date.Month && datecalendar1.Year == calendar.SelectedDate.Date.Year)
                                {
                                    int CurrentMonth = calendar.SelectedDate.Month;
                                    int CurrentYear = calendar.SelectedDate.Year;

                                    // Set the start and end dates.
                                    DateTime BeginDate = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, Convert.ToInt32(calendar.SelectedDate.Day));
                                    DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth,Convert.ToInt32(datecalendar1.Date.Day) );

                                    // Clear any selected dates.
                                    //calendar.SelectedDates.Clear();

                                    // Select the specified range of dates.
                                    calendar.SelectedDates.SelectRange(BeginDate, EndDate);
                                    for (BeginDate = BeginDate.Date; BeginDate <= EndDate; BeginDate.AddDays(1))
                                    {
                                        list.Add(BeginDate);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    else
                        list.Add(e.Day.Date);

                }
                Session["SelectedDates"] = list;
}
```

`````
 protected void Calendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
            {
                List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
                foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
                {


                    calendar.SelectedDates.Add(dt);


                     calendar.SelectedDates.Contains(calendar.SelectedDate.Date);
                }
                list.Clear();
            }
        }
````
````
   protected void btn_save_Click_Calendar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                List<DateTime> list = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    Dates.Add(new XElement("dt", new XAttribute("d", DateTime.Parse(item.ToShortDateString(), new CultureInfo("en-GB")))));
                }


               util._db.Ins_Leaveplanning(Convert.ToInt32(Session["empId"]),Dates.ToString());
                util.ShowMessage(util.Saved, util.MessageType.Success);
            }
`````

Comment: Check if [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/09/tiptrick-aspnet-calendar-control-with-multiple-date-selections.aspx) help you.

Comment: if i select 5th and 9th on calendar 5th to 9th should get selected

Comment: I don't code in asp, so I can't help you. I just searched in google and found that link. You should modify the code to your needs.